# Is there a way to compute if(i < j) k := (a + b)c with polynomials over $\Bbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: functions, polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity

Let $p$ be a prime and let all variables be in $\Bbb{Z}_p$.

Then you can write the result of

```
if(i > 0)
   k = (a + b)c;
```

(C code)

as a polynomial $k := i^{p-1} (a+b)c + (1 - i^{p-1}) k$  (notice $:=$ and not $=$).  But what about

```
if (i > j)
    k = (a + b)c;
```

?

If you try converting $i \gt j$ when your ordering on $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is $0, 1 \lt 2 \lt \dots \lt p-1 $, then we have that $i - j \gt 0 \not\implies i \gt j$, but the converse holds.

Then how can we construct a polynomial $F$ in $i,j,k,a,b,c$ such that $k := F(i,j,k,a,b,c)$ yields the same computation?

I bet there is one!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function $f$ from $\Bbb Z_p$ to $\Bbb Z_p$ can be written as a polynomial: by Fermat's little theorem,
$$
f(i) = \sum_{t=0}^{p-1} f(t)\big( 1-(i-t)^{p-1} \big).
$$
In your case, you want the answer to be $k$ when $0\le i\le j$ and $(a+b)c$ when $j<i\le p+1$; so the appropriate polynomial is
$$
f(i) = k \sum_{t=0}^{j} \big( 1-(i-t)^{p-1} \big) + (a+b)c \sum_{t=j+1}^{p-1} \big( 1-(i-t)^{p-1} \big).
$$
You can look for simpler expressions for this polynomial if you want; it's the unique polynomial of degree at most $p-1$ that does the trick.

Comment: Your summations don't make any sense (no use of $t$), and why $a$?  That's just some arb. value in some data memory slot.

Comment: Could you provide a link to an article on *FLT*?  I'm not finding anything related to this.

Comment: I think you mean $f(i) = \sum_{t=0}^{p-1} f(t) (1 - (i-t)^{p-1})$.

Comment: typos fixed (changed most $a$s to $t$s)

Comment: not surprisingly, a link is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem